# Django Framworks: URL error? my tutor has no clue

Tags: django, url

Maybe you could help me with the following issue, I'm following a course and changing the code for my own project.

Original code: https://github.com/ckz8780/boutique_ado_v1
My project: https://github.com/asforrest/Milestone-4-CarFix

The issue is coming from this page: https://8000-brown-earwig-xhtc2sv5.ws-eu03.gitpod.io/subscriptions/

And has to do with this app: https://github.com/asforrest/Milestone-4-CarFix/tree/master/subscriptions

My subscriptions (2 of them) are automatically displayed on the page above. But when I connect them to subscription_details I should get the URL back subscriptions/1 where 1 is the product_id.

However I get the error you see when clicking the link above.

Any help is grately apprechiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your  **subscriptions.urls** as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.all_subscriptions, name='subscriptions'),
    path('<int:subscription_id>', views.subscription_detail, name='subscription_detail'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I needed the < >